# List View empties after searched item not found and remains empty even after i clear the searched item

Tags: android, listview, search, android-contacts

i have a list view in which i show recent contacts and i have Edittext through which i search my recent list . Everything is perfect when i search but problem arises when the searched item is not found and list becomes empty and remains empty even after i clear my search edit text.

Please tell me where i am making mistake.

Here is my code.

**RecentContactAdapter**

```
public class RecentContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
ArrayList<Contacts> coverList;
public  ArrayList<Contacts> orig;
private ColorGenerator mColorGenerator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
private TextDrawable.IBuilder mDrawableBuilder;
public RecentContactsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Contacts> coverList)
{
    super();
    mContext = c;
    this.coverList = coverList;
    this.orig = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    this.orig.addAll(coverList);

}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return coverList.size();
}

@Override
public Contacts getItem(int position) {
    return coverList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
{



    return grid;
}

public void filter(String charText)
{
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    coverList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0)
    {
        coverList.addAll(orig);
    }

    else
    {
        for (Contacts wp : orig)
        {
            if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText) || wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText) || wp.getNumber().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText))
            {

                if(coverList.contains(wp))
                {}
                else {
                    coverList.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

**RecentContactFragment**

```
public class RecentContactsTab extends Fragment
{
View v;
Context c;
public static ListView rec_list;
ArrayList<Contacts> recent_list;
public static RecentContactsAdapter rec_ContactsAdapter;
ProgressDialog pd;
public static String number;
boolean appInstalled;
public static String email;
EditText search;
Functions functions;
VariableListener mCallback;
TextView noContact;
RecentContactsAdapter search_adapter;
RelativeLayout list;


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    try {
        mCallback = (VariableListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ Log.e("STEP","1");
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recent_layout, container, false);
    c = this.getActivity();

    rec_list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact);
    recent_list = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    search= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.recentsearch);

    v.findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
    noContact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rec_noContact);
    list= (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.leftSide);
    tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();

    mCallback.onVariableListener(0);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        new GetCotact().execute();
    } else
        {
        functions = new Functions(c);
        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(c) && functions.checkpermission()) {
            new GetCotact().execute();
        } else {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(c)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this.getActivity(), AllPermissions.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else if (!functions.checkpermission()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this.getActivity(), AllPermissions.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }

   rec_list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    setupSearchView();
    return v;
}

private void setupSearchView() {

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
        {
            String text = search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

            if (recent_list.size() > 0)
            {
                rec_ContactsAdapter.filter(text);
            }

            else
            {
                    rec_ContactsAdapter = new RecentContactsAdapter(getActivity(), recent_list);
                    rec_list.setAdapter(rec_ContactsAdapter);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            search_adapter = new RecentContactsAdapter(getActivity(), recent_list);
            rec_list.setAdapter(rec_ContactsAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

class GetCotact extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.e("STEP","2");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        rec_ContactsAdapter = new RecentContactsAdapter(c, recent_list);
        search_adapter=rec_ContactsAdapter;
        rec_list.setAdapter(rec_ContactsAdapter);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        readContacts();
        return null;

    }
}

private void readContacts() {
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    }
    else
    {
        Cursor cur = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls._ID + " DESC");
        String phone = null;
        String emailContact = null;
        String image_uri = null;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        String name;


        if (cur.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while (cur.moveToNext())
            {
                Log.e("STEP","3");
                name = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                phone=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));

                if (name==null)
                {
                    name=" ";
                    phone=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));

                    image_uri=null;
                }
                else
                {
                    name = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                }

                recent_list.add(new Contacts(name, phone, image_uri,emailContact));
                emailContact="";
                phone="";
            }
            cur.close();
        }
        else
        {
            noContact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            noContact.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.default_color));
            noContact.setText("No Recent Contacts");
            list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    Log.e("STEP","4");
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following lines :

```
 if (recent_list.size() > 0)
        {
            rec_ContactsAdapter.filter(text);
        }

        else
        {
                rec_ContactsAdapter = new RecentContactsAdapter(getActivity(), recent_list);
                rec_list.setAdapter(rec_ContactsAdapter);

        }
```

With :

```
rec_ContactsAdapter.filter(text);
```

And also remove from afterTextChanged():

```
 search_adapter = new RecentContactsAdapter(getActivity(), recent_list);
 rec_list.setAdapter(rec_ContactsAdapter);
```

Comment: can you explain this in detail

Comment: You are setting the whole adapter again when length becomes 0. You do not need to do that. You just have to add the previous list again like you do in filter method when length become 0.

Answer (score 0):

Change your below code

```
if (charText.length() == 0)
{
    coverList.addAll(orig);
}
```

with this

```
if (charText.length() == 0)
{
    coverList.addAll(orig);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

That will work for you.